# Inconsistency when calling in-proc registration-free com servcer from c#

Tags: c#, com, sta

I've encountered strange behavior when using registration-free com component. Here is what i have:

1. Com component. I dont know what threading model it is designed for
   as i dont have source codes, but it works in STA for sure.
2. Manifest for that com-component (manifestA)
3. c# application (wpf, vs2010, ui thread is sta)

Following code is used to instantiate server:

```
var t = new Thread(CreateServer) { Name = "Server", IsBackground = true };
t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
t.Start();
```

CreateServer is as follows:

```
 public static void CreateServer()
  {
    Service = new Service();
    Service.Connect();
    /* start message queue*/
    Dispatcher.Run();
  }
```

code in wpf application:

```
new Thread(() => { GetServer().DoStuff(); }.Start();
```

So when i run an application, com methods are actually runs on main STA thread and blocks UI.

Now if i set threadingModel="Apartment" in manifestA it wont affect anything. But if **recompile** application after changing threading model, com server starts to works on dedicated thread.

I searched a lot but could not find why this is happening. Why manifestA takes affect during compilation only?

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Because the manifest is embedded in the EXE.  So recompiling is necessary to make it have an effect.

Comment: Com configuration is in external file which is referenced from exes manifest. Am i missing something?

Comment: Manifest info is cached. On Win7 aggressively. Start application, delete `manifestA` and start it again. Does it fail? `Touch` executable flushes manifest cache for the app.